# Trying to use PowerShell to install Microsoft sql management studio (ssms)

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell, ssms

I'm trying to install Microsoft sql server management studio on my AWS windows server and I keep getting this error on PowerShell

```
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
$here = pwd
$software = "SQL Server Management Studio";
$installed = (Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* | Where { $_.DisplayName -eq $software }) -ne $null



#If SQSS was not installed before, it will be download required files and install it.
If(-Not $installed)
{
Write-Host "'$software' is NOT installed.";
wget https://aka.ms/ssmsfullsetup -outfile "SSMS-Setup-ENU.exe"
.\SSMS-Setup-ENU.exe /install /quiet /norestart
}
#If SQSS was installed before, it will try to update it to the newer version, if available.
#If no updates available, it will do nothing.
else
{
Write-Host "'$software' is installed."
if ( Test-Path -Path $here\SSMS-Setup-ENU.exe )
{
.\SSMS-Setup-ENU.exe /update /quiet /norestart
}
else {
wget https://aka.ms/ssmsfullsetup -outfile "SSMS-Setup-ENU.exe"
.\SSMS-Setup-ENU.exe /update /quiet /norestart
}
}
```

Here is the error I keep getting

wget : The remote name could not be resolved: 'download.microsoft.com'

At C:\Temp\mqss-1.ps1:12 char:1

- wget https://aka.ms/ssmsfullsetup -outfile "SSMS-Setup-ENU.exe"
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-WebRequest], WebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand
  ```

Comment: There is no /update option when looking at the command line switches. Not sure that's your issue but it stood out to me. You can run `.\ssms-setup-enu.exe /?` to see the options

Answer (score 0):

Continuing from my comment. The installer does not offer an `/update` switch, so you can just use install for both. I would use `Start-Process` to execute the command and let it provide the array of arguments to it.

```
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
Push-Location $env:temp
$software = "SQL Server Management Studio"
$installed = (Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* | Where-Object DisplayName -eq $software )

If(-Not $installed){
    Write-Verbose "'$software' is NOT installed, installing" -Verbose
}
else{
    Write-Verbose "'$software' is installed, updating" -Verbose
}

Write-Verbose "Downloading SSMS-Setup-ENU.exe" -Verbose

try{
    Invoke-WebRequest https://aka.ms/ssmsfullsetup -OutFile '.\SSMS-Setup-ENU.exe' -ErrorAction Stop
}
catch{
    Write-Warning "Error downloading file: $($_.exception.message)"
    break
}

$arguments = "/install","/quiet","/norestart"

Write-Verbose "Executing 'SSMS-Setup-ENU.exe $arguments'" -Verbose

try{
    $result = Start-Process .\SSMS-Setup-ENU.exe -ArgumentList $arguments -PassThru -Wait
}
catch{
    Write-Warning $_.exception.message
}

switch -Exact($result.ExitCode){
    1603 {
        Write-Verbose "Reboot is required" -Verbose
    }

    0 {
        Write-Verbose "Installation successful" -Verbose
    }

    default{
        Write-Verbose "Installation was not successful" -Verbose
    }
}
```